# Step by Step debugging with DevExtreme

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, devextreme

i'm new in devextreme development, i would like to develop an android application. Can i debug step by step, using breakpoints a devextreme application on simulator or device?
I tried Courier App on Android and it seems you can only run the app,not debug.
Also simulator on chrome doesn't stop on breakpoints.

Answer (score 3):

I see the following ways to go:

- for desktop you can debug your application in DevExtreme simulator with developer tools available (e.g. DevTools for Chrome). Just open DevTools and set necessary breakpoints or put debugger; line in your code where you need to debug.
- for device use remote debugging available in Chrome. Check out how to use it https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Than you so much for you answer!